# Including a custom node module in react.js project causing "Uncaught Type Error : exists is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react.js project in which I would like to use a custom node module which is a private repository in github. I include the module in **package.json** as follows

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-module": "git+https://<oauthtoken>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myname/custom-module"
  }
}
```

When I do `npm install` and do the following in one of the models in my react app

```
var customModule = require('custom-module');
```

and load the app in the browser, I am getting the following error browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function
  package.discover @ (index):110233
  package @ (index):110207420
  ../lib/dir @ (index):109791
```

Why am I getting this error?

**NOTE:** The same custom module is working fine in a server side node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

What are the contents of package.json?
Are you sure you have used --save when using npm install?

Comment: Oversight from my end, what the error actually tells you is that custom-module is not a function, meaning it cannot be called as custom-module().
Check the export of custom-module and make sure you are not returning an object literal.